# How to write books_path(user_id: current_user) in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I write books_path(user_id: current_user) in the routes.rb, where there is currently:

```rb
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'books#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

In the url, it looks like:

http://localhost:3000/books?user_id=1

I have tried get 'books/:user_id' to: 'books#index' and such that I found on the rails guide, but none worked.

Comment: Could you please list your routing attempts and the errors that resulted from them?

Comment: @ianrandmckenzie What I tried is about the same as yours. Led to "Welcome to Rails!" page... (the thing that we see in the very beginning of rails). not sure why. Either that, or stayed in the same page without the books listed.

Answer (score 0):

Because `books#index` is intended to list ALL books, I would suggest creating a custom action on your `BooksController`:

```rb
def user_books
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @books = user.books # assuming User has_many Books
end
```

Create your view accordingly in `app/views/books/user_books.html.erb`

Then in routes (note the comments):

```rb
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root 'books#index', as: :authenticated_root
    # http://localhost:3000/users/1/books
    get '/users/:user_id/books', to: 'books#user_books'
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that when I use @books as you suggested, I cannot do one feature: going from a comment of a user (on post index) to that user's book list (book index). For it, I seem to have to -- maybe there's another way -- use ```@books = Book.where(user: params[:user_id])```.